# Chrome: The input value is blank when used saved password

Tags: html, google-chrome, input

I thins it's bug. I want to know if someone experience it.

When I open "Login" page, with input password that the browser (chrome) remember it, and automatic put the value (displayed using sprockets).

Both the JS and C# (PostBack) tell me that the value of the input-password is blank.

Thank for any idea.

My Chrome ver is: 33.0.1750.5 dev-m

Comment: You means, you have already save username and password but it doesnot showing on the textbox?

Comment: No. I means the userName showing, the password showing dotted. And It is not detected!

Comment: Have you put autocomplete='off' on your textbox

Comment: Sorry, I edited my comment....

Comment: dotted means what? Is it showing in password char.

Comment: The default input-password visibility.... **********

Comment: When I retype the (same) password again... It's work!

Comment: The password isn't auto-loaded until after the page is fully loaded.  The Javascript only initially sees what is there as the page is loading, so that password value isn't there yet.

Comment: I do not think this is indeed the problem. It's happening also after waiting time. Besides that, the C# also not recognize the value....

Comment: Sounds like a safety issue, where a malicious script inserted on a page wouldn't be able to read automatically filled in credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was bug!! They fixed it. (Version 33.0.1750.22 dev-m)

Thanks all!